# Trying to convert hh:mi:ss to hhmiss in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.5, sql-timestamp

So I've been trying to convert the time in one of the columns in my table. The time column in the table has the format hh:mi:ss but I need it to be in the format hhmiss without the colons;  so far I've tried this:

```
SELECT
    time_utc
FROM
    particle_counter_hisam
WHERE
    time_utc = CONVERT (VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108)
```

But I get this error:

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "," LINE 3: where time_utc =
>   CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 108)

I have no clue here why I get this error, please some help would be awesome I am relatively new in SQL.

Comment: Where in the Postgres manual did you find `convert()` and `getdate()`?

Comment: I found this command on an sql website, I was trying to find someone that has tried to dot he same thing than me and that is what I found.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [to_char](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-formatting.html) in postgresql:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(time_utc, 'hh24miss')
FROM particle_counter_hisam
```

Comment: that sort of worked, but I in my data the times are recorded as 15:34:17 and after i used your code it only output 033417 , instead of 153417, the other thing is that i need this changes to be made in the table permanently. It only a data output of that specific column without changin anything in the table.

Comment: You can try HH24 instead of hh, yes what gordon said. The database itself has a standard format it will use. You can only change the output.

Comment: I see, is there a way to change the standard format, because I really need to change the time stamp into the ouput i am getting. In  other words can you even modify your table at all?

Comment: No the database has a format it takes but provides many options for output.

Comment: can you save your output as a .csv file?